# using Javascript to get unique XML child nodes

Tags: javascript, php, xml, codeigniter, google-maps

I'm a noob trying to build a map for my Com. Prog. class with the Google Maps API.

I have data that I want to output as markers and infowindows.

I used Codeigniter to output an XML from my database. (data modified for privacy)

```
<markers>
    <item0>
        <city>Boston</city>
        <latitude>0.01111</longitude>
        <longitude>1.2345</longitude>
    </item0>
    <item1>
        <city>Los Angeles</city>
        <latitude>9.99999</latitude>
        <longitude>2.00011</longitude>
    </item1>
</markers>
```

Now I'm trying to use Javascript to get all the child nodes of each "item" tag.

My callback function:

```
var xml = data.responseXML;
var items = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("markers");

// for loop iterates through each the child nodes of the "item" tags.

Array.prototype.forEach.call(items, function(markerElem) {
var city = nodeValue(markersElem.children.item[0]);
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
parseFloat(nodeValue(markersElem.children.item[1])),
parseFloat(nodeValue(markersElem.children.item[2])));
});
```

The main problem (I believe) is that the "item" tags each contain a unique number, so I can't call them with the getElementsByTagName method.

I've tried modifying the items variable to get the children nodes of the "markers" tag:

```
var items = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("markers").children;
```

But the console outputs an error where the items variable is now undefined.

I've also tried to modify the XML file, but I can only seem to output XML through Codeigniter's built-in helper. Maybe there is a way to create a DOM document in PHP 7 that I don't know about?

Comment: Here's how to extract the data: https://jsfiddle.net/ht38g9vq/ (note that if you output as JSON instead, that entire conversion code becomes unnecessary)

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier if you convert **XML** in your controller with the **`simplexml_load_string()`** to a **PHP** array or object and then use the **`json_encode()`** to convert it to JSON format, so it will be much easier to work with this **JSON** array or object in **JS** code.
In your controller do this and send it to your view:

```
json_encode(simplexml_load_string(your XML here), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you would use [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) for that it will allow you to pull all the element  under a cetrain path which you can  then iterate over as normal.